# How to follow a TOC link with keyboard in Microsoft Word 2007

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, microsoft-word-2007

I prefer to use the mouse as little as possible. So far I have not been able to find a way to follow a TOC (table of contents) link in Microsoft Word using the keyboard.

My goal is to be able to quickly navigate through the document using the TOC and the keyboard.

The [Document Map](http://www.shaunakelly.com/word/numbering/documentmap.html) would probably work well for this, but in Word 2007 it appears to not be able to get keyboard focus, so it only works with the mouse.

Is there any way to do this with the keyboard?

Comment: It appears that this is just not possible in Word 2007.

Comment: I stand, happily, corrected! Thanks, Lernkurve!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solution**

Assign a custom keyboard shortcut to the HyperlinkOpen command.

**How to**

Don't know whether it works the same way in Word 2007, but in Word 2010 do the following:

1. Menu: File > Options
2. Section: Customize Ribbon
3. Button: Customize... next to Keyboard shortcuts
   [image]
4. Categories: All commands
5. Commands: HyperlinkOpen
6. Assign a keyboard shortcut of your choice, for example <kbd>F12</kbd>
7. Button: Assign
8. Button: Close
9. Button: Ok

**Usage**

Now, when the cursor is over a hyperlink on the TOC, press <kbd>F12</kbd>, and there you go.

Answer (score 4):

Press <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F10</kbd> to open the context menu, then press <kbd>O</kbd> to select `Open Hyperlink`.

Comment: I was going to say the same thing, except use the [Right-Click] button on the keyboard instead of [Shift]+[F10].

Comment: @Hand: I would have said that, except that many modern keyboards no longer include that button (especially laptops)

Comment: What?!  That key's invaluable.  :-(

Comment: That menu item works for hyperlinks, but not for TOC links. I'm realizing that the title of my question is a bit misleading; changing it now.

Answer (score 2):

If you hit <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>home</kbd> Word will open up a little box that allows you to set the current browsing type (Browse Options).

These option effects what <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>PgUp</kbd> and <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>PgDn</kbd> do.

If you open the Browse Option dialog and select "Browse by field", then  <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>PgUp</kbd> and <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>PgDn</kbd> will jump from field to field in the document.  Since hyperlinks count as fields, they will be one of the things it stops on.

Comment: That's useful, thank you! It's not quite what I'm looking for, though. I'm not trying to get to the hyperlinks, I'm trying to get to the hyperlink targets, when I'm already at the hyperlink.